# Program stops working on 2nd runthrough

Tags: vba, excel

Visual Basic Problem:

Hello Friends,

my problem is pretty complex (although the solution is most likely an easy one):

I've written a small application in Visual Basic. It's a small time management system that has 4 simple functions (on separate buttons):

"Start Work:"

Fetch the current date from System, compare it to a list of dates in an excel table, set current row to the row with the fitting date, and enter the current time in the appropriate cell.

The other functions are "stop work", "start break" and "stop break" and work pretty much the same way.

The application is started by a button embedded in the form and works - so far so good. If I however, start VBA's own debugger and then start the Program again, it fails, because the function that sniffs the correct date out of the list of dates fails to find the correct value. At this point I'm pretty much out of ideas (especially since this is my first VBA project) so I'd be really glad if someone could give me a pointer in the right direction.

Here's the function fetching the date:

```
Function get_date(time As Date)             'findet das aktuelle Datum in Spalte 2 (Datum)

    Dim findDate As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set findDate = Columns(2).Find(Date)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    If findDate Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Current Date not on Active Form!"
    Else: MsgBox "Current Date is " & Date
    MsgBox findDate
    Exit Function
    End If


End Function
```

and the function setting the row to the row with the current date

```
Function get_row(time As Date)

Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
Set rngSearch = Range("B5:B18")
Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=Date, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If rngFound Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Aktuelles Datum nicht gefunden - Terminplan erweitern"
Else
get_row = rngFound.row
End If

End Function
```

As I mentioned both those functionalities work perfectly fine on the first start-up of the form but fail to find (and thus return) a value if I debug and start the Makro again.

The program also has a real time running clock on a timer - maybe that's a factor? I'm totally lost to be honest.

Any criticisms towards the code and how I tackled certain problems are also very welcome - this is my first VBA app ever.

Update:

As requested here's a screenshot of what I assume to be the search ranges:

[image: Search Ranges]

I'm using the 1904 date system, but changing back to 1900 didn't have any effect.

If anyone is interested, I uploaded the whole Project into my github [Stechuhr.xlsm](https://github.com/MartinSchmid1602/VBA)

The relevant file is "Stechuhr.xlsm"

Any further help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: To clarify - The program stops working, once it has been **paused and then resumed**. I suspect that the timer function is somehow responsible for this - will do further testing.

Update 2:

As I have been unable to fix this, I simplified my problem as suggested:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function FindDateRowInColB(TargetDate As Date, TargetSheet As Worksheet) As Long

    Dim FoundRange As Range
    Set FoundRange = TargetSheet.Columns(2).Find(What:=TargetDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        FindDateRowInColB = 0
    Else
        FindDateRowInColB = FoundRange.Row
    End If

End Function

'Test Button 1

Private Sub Test_button_Click()

    Dim TestTime As Date
    Dim TestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TestRow As Long
    Dim pdat_Datum As Date

    pdat_Datum = Date

    'set references
    Set TestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

    'this is our test assertion
    TestRow = FindDateRowInColB(pdat_Datum, TestSheet)

    'short if statement to display a message based on test results
    MsgBox ("TestRow =" & TestRow)

End Sub

' Test Button 2

Private Sub TestButton_2_Click()

    Dim active_row As Integer
    Dim pdat_aktuellesDatum As Date
    Dim TestSheet As Worksheet

   pdat_aktuellesDatum = Date

   Set TestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

     'set references
    Set TestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

    active_row = FindDateRowInColB(pdat_aktuellesDatum, TestSheet)

    MsgBox ("Die passende Reihe zum heutigen Datum ist " & active_row)
End Sub
```

There's the code. It's simply one function and 2 buttons to test it. However, it has the very same problems as my original code - works fine on first startup, but if I ever pause the program and start it again, FindDateRowInColB always returns a value of null. I suppose there might be some memory management issue at work.

If anyone has further input, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your search is trying to find `Date` in the `get_row` function -- should it be looking for the input variable `time` instead?

Comment: No. The get_row function is indeed looking for the date. The program runs something like this: Search for date in range B5-B18 -> return the row the date is in -> set that row to active -> put time value in active row. I hope it is more clear now. It is especially puzzling since the program runs perfectly fine if I never touch the debugger

Comment: In `get_date` I believe `Set findDate = Columns(2).Find(Date)` should be `Set findDate = Columns(2).Find(time)`.  `time` is the parameter; `Date` is its type. There is a similar issue in `get_row`.

Comment: `get_date` is a function but does not return a value.  There may be further errors but these jump out at me.

Comment: Hey Tony, great eye here -- I think you're noticing the same (potential) issue I commented on above. @Fang's response indicates however that this is not the problem, which makes it all the more interesting...

Comment: I'll experiment further in a few hours, and try to build on the ideas you two gave me. Thanks a lot so far

Comment: @DanWagner. Sorry For duplicating your comment;  I should have read it more carefully.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` to prevent (or at least alert you to) typographical errors or misidentified variables...

Comment: As to that: Of course you guys were right - the function should have read time. In effect though, it was meaningless - VBA interpreted Date as what I suppose is the current system date. Probably one of the properties of the language. Since the System Date is supposed to be referenced here, changing date to "time" didn't mean a thing. It is however, a mistake, and I corrected it accordingly

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or two of the lookup ranges?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a lightweight test environment for your functions to make sure they are returning what you'd expect for a few conditions. Here is an example function for finding a date match in column B along with two tests:

[image: test]

```
Option Explicit
Public Function FindDateRowInColB(TargetDate As Date, TargetSheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim FoundRange As Range
    Set FoundRange = TargetSheet.Columns(2).Find(What:=TargetDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        FindDateRowInColB = 0
    Else
        FindDateRowInColB = FoundRange.Row
    End If
End Function

Sub TestFindDateRowFunctionSuccess()

Dim TestTime As Date
Dim TestSheet As Worksheet
Dim TestRow As Long

'set references
Set TestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
TestTime = "4/22/2014"

'this is our test assertion
TestRow = FindDateRowInColB(TestTime, TestSheet)

'short if statement to display a message based on test results
If TestRow = 3 Then
    MsgBox ("Test passed! Identified 4/22/2014 in row 3")
Else
    MsgBox ("Test failed! Did not identify 4/22/2014 in row 3")
End If

End Sub

Sub TestFindDateRowFunctionFailure()

Dim TestTime As Date
Dim TestSheet As Worksheet
Dim TestRow As Long

'set references
Set TestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
TestTime = "4/1/2014"

'this is our test assertion
TestRow = FindDateRowInColB(TestTime, TestSheet)

'short if statement to display a message based on test results
If TestRow = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Test passed! Date 4/1/2014 was not found so 0 was returned")
Else
    MsgBox ("Test failed! Date 4/1/2014 was identified somewhere")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: As I said, the true problem is that the function works perfectly fine the first time, then fails to return the correct value after running the debugger. Thanks anyway, I hope to know more by tonight.

Comment: Hey @Fang, the code in the function and test scripts above worked correctly over and over in a variety of configurations

Comment: Dear Dan, I incorporated your function in my Program - it works, albeit with the very same problem that my function has. Once I stop the Program, Debug, and Restart the program fails to find the correct date. The error must be somewhere else, but I cannot figure out where :(